# allow webalizer in selinux (centos)

Tags: centos, selinux

I roughly followed these instructions: http://library.linode.com/web-applications/analytics/webalizer/centos-5 to install and configure webalizer to run on several VirtualHosts. Unfortunately when i try and run:

`webalizer -n site.net -o /var/www/webalizer /etc/httpd/logs/site.net-apache_log`

I get:

`Error: Can't open log file /etc/httpd/logs/site.net-apache_log`

But after running:

`echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`

It works.

How can i tell selinux to allow webalizer to run?

*EDIT*

```
[root@web-01 logs]# ls -lZ
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 access_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 error_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 tt.net-access_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 tt.net-error_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 ck.tt.net-access_log
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 ck.tt.net-error_log
```

.

```
[root@web-01 ~]# service --status-all
auditd (pid  1132) is running...

[root@web-01 ~]# /opt/webalizerScript.sh 
Error: Can't open log file /etc/httpd/logs/tt.net-access_log
Error: Can't open log file /etc/httpd/logs/ck.tt.net-access_log

[root@web-01 ~]# audit2allow -w -a
<no matches>
```

Comment: What user is webalizer running as, and what's the output of `ls -lZ` on the log files? (Please add this to the question.)

Comment: i've added the output of `ls -lZ`. webalizer runs via cron- my linux knowledge isn't great- but i think that means it runs as root?

Answer (score 2):

Use `audit2allow` to determine why webalizer was blocked and to build a local SELinux policy module to allow webalizer to access the necessary files.

Red Hat's [SELinux Troubleshooting Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html) has [detailed steps on this process](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html).

Comment: there are no entries in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, the command `audit2allow` doesn't exist & `yum install audit2allow` says there is no package available. Any ideas?

Comment: Install them? `yum install audit policycoreutils-python`

Comment: `policycoreutils-python` fixed the missing `audit2allow` but no entries appear when webalizer runs/fails?

Comment: You didn't have the `auditd` service running. Start it and try again from the beginning.

Comment: added to my original question. i retried the troublesome command with auditd running- still nothing :(
thanks for keeping trying- appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem to run webalizer on a log I created by combining 2 httpd logs (access_log and ssl_acces_log concatened and sorted by date). It was perfectly running with either of the 2 files, but with the combination of both, i got the "Can't open log file" mesasge.

There was no trace of any error in the audit.log, as for Lee.

However, by executing this command:

```
chcon --type=httpd_log_t /var/log/combined-httpd.log
```

webalizer was finally authorized to read the file...